# How to make long URLs friendly with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo, friendly-url

I have a project am working on but I got a problem.

**Problem**

Main GET data: `www.enterr.com/profile.php?username=beraki`

Will be : `www.enterr.com/beraki` **This is ok**

But I have a 2 GET data url : `www.enterr.com/profile.php?username=beraki&mode=about`
I would like it to be : `www.enterr.com/beraki/about`

And if I have a 3 GET data url I want them all to be friendly as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for two get data:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ profile.php?dataone=$1&datatwo=$2
```

Try this for three get data:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ profile.php?dataone=$1&datatwo=$2&datathree=$3
```

The above codes work, checked it. Just replace dataone, datatwo, datathree with the data you are passing.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1&mode=$2&third=$3
```